# How to insert partial source code in SAS?

Tags: sql, input, insert, include, sas

My data is a SAS Table with 50k rows and 300 columns.

Here I make a little example with only 10 columns. Let's say that 3 colums are refecence and the other are variable columns.

Here is my SAS programm:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.MATRIX(label="MATRIX with variable columns") AS
SELECT t1.REFERENCE_1,
       t1.REFERENCE_2,
       t1.REFERENCE_3,

       t1.COLUMN_A, 
       t1.COLUMN_B,
       t1.COLUMN_C,
       t1.COLUMN_D,
       t1.COLUMN_E,
       t1.COLUMN_F,
       t1.COLUMN_G

-------     
 Variable souce code which makes operation on these columns
-------

FROM WORK.MY_DATA t1;
QUIT;
```

I alreary have a SAS code that gives me source code for a given choice of columns. Here is the output of my SAS code:

```
        t1.COLUMN_B, 
        t1.COLUMN_D,
        t1.COLUMN_G,
```

I can now store this code here „c:\My_columns_choice.txt“.
This is what I would like to have:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.MATRIX(label="MATRIX with variable columns") AS 
SELECT t1.REFERENCE_1,
       t1.REFERENCE_2,
       t1.REFERENCE_3,

INSERT „c:\My_columns_choice.txt“

INSERT „c:\My_source_code_which_makes_operations.txt“

FROM WORK.MY_DATA t1;
QUIT;
```

So the question arises as follow, is this possible to insert partial source code in SAS programm through a sort of function like INSERT?
What is the correct syntax?

Many thanks.
Cheers

Mauri

Answer (score 1):

You can use %INCLUDE to include multiple lines of code, but you cannot use that to include parts of a statement.  But you can use a macro variable to generate code that could be just part of a statement. For example you could make a macro variable that has a comma separated list of column references.

```
%let varlist=t1.COLUMN_B,t1.COLUMN_D,t1.COLUMN_G;
```

Then you can reference the macro variable where you want to insert the text.

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE MATRIX(label="MATRIX with variable columns") AS 
    SELECT t1.REFERENCE_1
         , t1.REFERENCE_2
         , t1.REFERENCE_3
         , &varlist   
    FROM MY_DATA t1
  ;
QUIT;
```

If you want to store this in a file you could either store it in the form or the `%LET` statement above and then just use `%INCLUDE` to run it in advance of your SQL statement so that the macro variable exists. Note that your file would then need to include full SAS statements and not just a part of a statement.

Or you could write a DATA step (or other code) to read the text file into the macro variable.  The advantage of using a DATA step to read the file is then the file can contain only part of a statement. For example here is a simple data step to read in a one line file and store it in a macro variable.

```
data _null_;
  infile 'column_list.txt' ;
  input;
  call symputx('VARLIST',_infile_);
run;
proc sql;
  ... &varlist ...
```

Comment: Could you please show your answer with the correct synthax `%INCLUDE`?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want?  Create a txt file that contains the %LET statement. Then in your actual program have a %INCLUDE statement to include that file so that the %LET statement is executed.

Comment: @Tom I did the following: I stored  `t1.COLUMN_B,t1.COLUMN_D,t1.COLUMN_G` in  "c:\My_columns_choice.txt“

Then I whote the following code:
%LET varlist=  "c:\My_columns_choice.txt“;
`PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE MATRIX(label="MATRIX with variable columns") AS 
    SELECT t1.REFERENCE_1,
                  t1.REFERENCE_2,
                  t1.REFERENCE_3,
                  &Varlist
        
    FROM MY_DATA t1;
QUIT; ` It doesn't work. Could you please show an example with `%INCLUDE`?

Comment: You cannot use %INCLUDE in the middle of a statement like that. That is what the first sentence in my answer explains.

Comment: %INCLUDE works fine in PROC SQL, but you cannot use it in the middle of a statement.

Comment: @Tom Your answer almost worked! I had 7 columns in 'column_list.txt' and I used your code:   `data _null_;
  infile 'column_list.txt' ;
  input;
  call symputx('VARLIST',_infile_);
run;
proc sql;
  ... &varlist ...` But in the output I only saw the the last column (7). I didn't saw the columns 1-6. Why?

Comment: Most likely your data file had one line per column name. So the data step looped 7 times and so only the last line was used to generate the macro variable since the other versions were overwritten.  Change the code that generates the macro to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `%INCLUDE` macro statement. Add `SOURCE2` option to obtain a log.

```
%INCLUDE 'c:\My_source_code_which_makes_operations.txt' / SOURCE2;
```

EDIT:

**`%include` is NOT a macro statement**, so in this special case (`proc sql`) it doesn't work. Only you can include the whole query, but a part of it is not acceptable.

To solve this problem you can read file using `data step` and create a macro variable, wich you put in `select` statement.

Example (only one line in text file):

```
filename f "/folders/myfolders/class.txt";
data _null_;
    infile f dlm='00'x lrecl=32767;
    length line $32767;
    input line;
    call symputx('vars', line);
run;

PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE class AS
    SELECT name,
        &vars
    FROM sashelp.class;
QUIT;
```

Comment: Could you please provide the whole correct synthax?  Because this code, provides an error.  `PROC SQL;  CREATE TABLE  WORK.MATRIX(label="MATRIX with variable columns") AS  SELECT t1.REFERENCE_1,‘
       t1.REFERENCE_2,
       t1.REFERENCE_3,

    %INCLUDE 'c:\My_source_code_which_makes_operations.txt' / SOURCE2;

    FROM WORK.MY_DATA t1;
    QUIT;` The two spaces at the end of the line do not work for a line break! :(

Comment: Sorry, this way doesn't work. It very strange for me, but somehow correct according to documentation. I think `PROC SQL` special place where you can't use `%include`.

Comment: I added other solution to the post.

Comment: `@Robert Sozyriski` I tried your solution and I have exactly the same probleme like wit the @Tom solution.  I had 7 columns in 'column_list.txt' and I used your code. But in the output I only saw the reference columns and the the last column (7). I didn't saw the columns 1-6. Why?